# NGRX state mutation

Tags: angular, redux, state, ngrx, mutation

I am developing an enterprise Angular project using Angular CLI and NGRX version 10.
Inside a component, I receive a state property via selector and then I change that object. I get no error and this is confusing for me because the state is immutable but it is muted without any error.

Comment: Please post some code like how you are getting the data via selector etc so that others can help you. Just a problem statement is not sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default ngrx doesn't detect such errors to improve performance.

If you want you can enable them during local development:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true, // <- what you need
        strictActionImmutability: true, // <- what you need
        strictStateSerializability: true,
        strictActionSerializability: true,
        strictActionWithinNgZone: true,
        strictActionTypeUniqueness: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

More info is here: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/configuration/runtime-checks

Comment: thanks you are right I found that in NGRX 8 the runtime checks were opt in and because of that there was no error with muting the state but in NGRX 9+ the checks are true by default and now I got the errors